# Broken font on JTable from database

Tags: java, database, swing, phpmyadmin, jtable

So I'm trying to show this data value on this table (The data came from PHPMYADMIN)

But it looks like this for some reason, is there any reason as to why it looks like this?

BTW: Netbeans didn't tell me there's an error:

[image: Squarey weirdy font(ERROR)]

Comment: I should think it would depend upon the Text Format from **phpMyAdmin** since it can export data in so many (CSV, SQL, XML, PDF, ISO/IEC 26300 - OpenDocument Text and Spreadsheet). You might want to check that.

Comment: Looks like a character encoding problem maybe. `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable` should show you the encoding and that should be used by the driver

Comment: Also you need to ensure that it's not a font problem, e.g. using a font that does not have the glyphs to display the characters you're using